Relay or Mosfet? I need to implement an emergency button in my system
I am implementing an emergency button for a medical device prototype and I was wondering what is the best option to switch the load off when the button is pressed: a mosfet or a relay?
The "load" in this case are 3 motors, two operating with 24V and nominal current of 2A and the other with 12V and 1A nominal current. I would like to turn them off in the event of emergency stop.

If this is a medical device, there will be very stringent standards of safety you have to meet. What do the motors do? Would a failure that requires pressing the emergency stop be of more danger to the operator or to the patient? (this is an important distinction for medical equipment standards)

more danger to the patient in this case...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
